# How to add text onto QToolbar with Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I would like to ask, if it is possible to add some text onto `QToolBar` with Qt Designer?

Comment: Qt Creator is just an IDE that does not intervene in how the widgets look, so I have removed that tag

Comment: @eyllanesc  Thanks for the help. But I really want to know how to do it using Qt Creator.

Comment: QtCreator doesn't matter in this case, you could use any other IDE and it should work too.

Comment: @eyllanesc Allright. So I am guessing I have to write the code, instead of using Qt Creator solely, right?

Comment: I think you are confusing QtCreator with QtDesigner, the first is an IDE and the second is a program that allows you to create the .ui that are converted into .h.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have Qt Creator 4.13.2. I am actually very satisfy with it.

Comment: QtCreator has QtDesigner as a design tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in Qt Designer, but it'd be a bad hack an unnecessary. Instead, do it via code. There are two ways:

1. `QToolBar` is a widget that graphically represents actions, represented by `QAction`. You can add an action that is pure text, using the `QToolBar::addAction(const QString &)`. E.g. if the toolbar object is simply called `toolbar`, you'd write `toolbar->addAction("Some text");`. This will create a button with given text, and return the corresponding action. Actions are an abstraction: they are devoid of a graphical representation, and they can be a part of multiple widgets (e.g. menus and toolbars). It's the individual widgets that give the actions some "physical shape", e.g. construct a button for each action.
2. `QToolBar`, at a lower level, is a collection of widgets, that you can add using `QToolBar::addWidget(QWidget *)`. So, if you want to add some static text, you'd create a label with that text and add it to the toolbar. The action thus created may not seem very useful, since you won't be reacting to the user clicking the text (see p.1 above if you do). But it could be used to show and hide the text if desired, and acts as a handle for the text, allowing you to change the text as well. It is really a `QWidgetAction` derived class. See below for some code to get you started.

```
// The text can be empty, in case it was meant to be set sometime later
QAction *addText(QToolBar *toolbar, const QString &text = {})
{
  auto *const label = new QLabel;
  auto *const action = toolbar->addWidget(label);
  // Any changes to the action's text should be propagated to the label.
  QObject::connect(action, &QAction::changed, label, [action,label]{
    label->setText(action->text());
  });

  action->setParent(toolbar); // so that the action won't leak
  action->setText(text);
  action->setVisible(true);
  return action;
}

// inside some method
auto *action = addText(toolbar, "Some text");
// sometime later
action->setText("Some other text");
```

A more flexible way of doing this would be to derive `QWidgetAction` to create e.g. `StaticTextAction`, and put the label creation code into `StaticTextAction::createWidget()`. But such flexibility is most likely unnecessary, since all you're after here is some static text that applies to the toolbar and has no other use (e.g. you wouldn't add it to any other widgets or menus).

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful!